# App label announcement upon opening `BottomSheetDialogFragment` with Compose content

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, talkback, bottomsheetdialogfragment

#### Problem

When opening a `BottomSheetDialogFragment`, with composable content, and TalkBack enabled, the app label is announced immediately. This is an unexpected and jarring experience for TalkBack users. Ideally announcement of the app label would not occur, which is what happens if the `BottomSheetDialogFragment` contains XML views.

#### Reproduction

Setup is as simple as this:

```kotlin
class ComposeBottomSheet : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.Theme_KeyboardExperiments_BottomSheetDialog)
        return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
            setContent {
               // Composables...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a sample project that can reproduce it [here](https://github.com/lukekivi/Keyboard-Experiments). This project was initially created to demonstrate a different bug... but it works here too. In this case the app label is `KeyboardExperiments`.

#### Demo

[image: Upon opening the sheet the app label is announced.]

#### Question

How can I skip the announcement of the app label upon opening a `BottomSheetDialogFragment` with composable content?

*Note: We cannot migrate to full Compose yet but that is the most obvious solution here.*

Comment: Have you tried to fully migrate to Compose?